# Groovy not converting seconds to hours properly

Tags: groovy

I have an integer that is:
19045800

I tried different code:

```
def c = Calendar.instance
c.clear()
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 19045800)
echo  c.format('HH:mm:ss').toString()
String timestamp = new GregorianCalendar( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19045800, 0 ).time.format( 'HH:mm:ss' )
echo timestamp
```

Both return 10:30:00

19045800 seconds is supposed to be over 5000 hours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You created a timestamp (time AND date), but from that, you just printed the time component …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. But if your requirement is to calculate the number of hours, minutes, and the remainder of seconds for given seconds following code will work.

```
def timeInSeconds = 19045800

int hours = timeInSeconds/3600 
int minutes = (timeInSeconds%3600)/60
int seconds = ((timeInSeconds%3600)%60)

println("Hours: " + hours)
println("Minutes: " + minutes)
println("Seconds: " + seconds)
```

Comment: I'm getting java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Share your latest code.

Comment: It was my fault. Sorry and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use a **Calendar**, but what you're actually discussing is what Java calls a **Duration** – a length of time in a particular measurement unit.

```
import java.time.*

def dur = Duration.ofSeconds(19045800)

def hours = dur.toHours()
def minutes = dur.minusHours(hours).toMinutes()
def seconds = dur.minusHours(hours).minusMinutes(minutes).toSeconds()

println "hours = ${hours}"
println "minutes = ${minutes}"
println "seconds = ${seconds}"
```

prints:

```
hours = 5290
minutes = 30
seconds = 0
```